# FQL Facebook Query - Get All Fields of Page Table

Tags: objective-c, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can I get all data fields of an Facebook FQL Table with one keyword ? for example SELECT ??? FROM page WHERE page_id == "myPageID" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify each column you want returned in the query. Yeah, it's a pain.
All the available columns:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/

Comment: oh damn so I have to write down each field .... It would be cool if there is a keyword like ALL().... but Thank you !!!!